# How to check if a DataTable row(s) has changed when using foreach?

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-2.0

I have the following code:

```
int sequence = 1; //This is incremented every time the Account changes
int numberOfItems; //This is reset after the Account changes
decimal totalAmount = 0m; //This is reset after the Account changes
string prevRow; //not sure how to handle this

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  //I am stuck here
  if(row["Account"]) == prevRow)
  {
  numberOfItems++;
  totalAmount += Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalAmount"]);
  }
  else
  {
     //reset everything and increase sequence
     numberOfItems = 0;
     totalAmount = 0m;
     sequence++
  }

}
```

My initial table may contain the data:

abc, 50.0
abc, 50.0
def, 60.0
ghi, 70.0

When looping through using for, the numberOfItems for abc should = 2, 1 for def, and 1 for ghi.  The totalAmount for abc should be 100.0, 60.0 for def and 70.0 for ghi.  The sequence should be 1 for abc, 2 for def, and 3 for ghi.

First thing I noticed when running the for loop is that it is skipping a bunch of rows in the first table, so when I create a second table in the else,  numberOfItems and totalAmount are still 0.  The second table should be something like:

abc, 100, 2, 1
def, 60, 1, 2
ghi, 70, 1, 3

where the last number in the csv values is the sequence and the number right before that is the numberOfItems per account.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
                DataRow prevRow = i > 0 ? dt.Rows[i - 1] : null;

                if (prevRow != null && row[1] == prevRow[1])
                {
                    numberOfItems++;
                    totalAmount += Convert.ToDecimal(row[2]);
                    row[3] = "D";
                    row[4] = c;
                    row[5] = sequence;

                }
                else
                {
                    dt2.Rows.Add("N",
                        c,
                        row[1],
                        row[2],
                        row[3],
                        numberOfItems,
                        totalAmount,
                        sequence);

                    numberOfItems = 0;
                    totalAmount = 0m;
                    sequence++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: A `foreach` doesn't know it's previous row. So why don't you simply use a `for-loop`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I thought about that.  How would I do it with that?  Would you mind providing an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `foreach` row doesn't know it's previous row. So why don't you simply use a `for-loop`?

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[ i ];
    DataRow prevRow = i > 0 ? dt.Rows[ i - 1 ] : null;

    if(prevRow != null && row["Account"] == prevRow["Account"])
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Now that you have updated your question i would suggest to use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<String>("Account"))
    .Select((g, i) => new { 
        Account = g.Key,
        TotalAmount = g.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("TotalAmount")),
        Count = g.Count(),
        Id = i + 1,
    });

foreach (var grp in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}"
        ,grp.Account, grp.TotalAmount, grp.Count, grp.Id);
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Tim, I am running into some issues with this.  I will update my post with an example and tell you what is happening

Comment: I wish I could use LINQ, but unfortunately, this is .net 2.0 and I can't

Comment: Also, maybe I should check the next row instead of the previous or does it matter, basically, I have a details DataTable and I am building a Summary DataTable off of that everytime I encounter a new Account Number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataTable.GetChanges`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649.aspx

```
var changeTable = table.GetChanges();
foreach(var item in changeTable.Rows)
{
 .....

}
```

For modified rows you can use argument `DataRowState.Modified`

```
table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

Comment: Do you have an example with my code above. Can I check for specific row changes?

Comment: He don't want to get the _changes_, he want to know if this row's field is equal to previous row's field.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sequence = 1; //This is incremented every time the Account changes
int numberOfItems; //This is reset after the Account changes
decimal totalAmount = 0m; //This is reset after the Account changes
string prevRow = null; //not sure how to handle this

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  //I am stuck here
  if((row["Account"]) == prevRow)
  {
  numberOfItems++;
  totalAmount += Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalAmount"]);
  }
  else
  {
     //reset everything and increase sequence
     numberOfItems = 0;
     totalAmount = 0m;
     sequence++;
  }
  prevRow = row["Account"];

}
```

Note that I've put a ; after the incrementation of sequence.

Comment: Your code will fail for the first account. On first running prevRow will be null, so you then set this to the current account, then on the next line check if the current account == the last account, which it always will for the first account.

Comment: Also, you have an extra closing bracket in the IF statement (copied over from the original code)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sequence = 1; //This is incremented every time the Account changes
int numberOfItems; //This is reset after the Account changes
decimal totalAmount = 0m; //This is reset after the Account changes
String prevAccount == ""; //not sure how to handle this

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   //I am stuck here
   if(row["Account"] == prevAccount)
   {
      numberOfItems++;
      totalAmount += Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalAmount"]);
   }
   else
   {
       //reset everything and increase sequence
       numberOfItems = 0;
       totalAmount = 0m;
       sequence++;
    }
    prevAccount = row["Account"];
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your implementation and Lajos's implementation?

Comment: I did not see his approach at first, but looking at it, there are two differences - he has an extra check to see if prevRow is null, which is not required if you initialise it to "" as I have done, also he has a typo on line 11 which would throw a compile error. (extra closing bracket in the IF statement)

Comment: also his code has a bug that will cause the first account to be skipped (see my comment to his answer)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.  I am trying your solution.

Comment: Look at my code update that has a more real example.  When I ran this it seemed to skip some rows.